# Laravel return flash session

Tags: laravel

Hey guys i'am having a trouble getting a flash message from my controller to my view if the user want a quantity more than the stock has .

this is the ajax request :

```
 element.addEventListener('change', function () {

            var rowId = element.getAttribute('data-id');
            var stock = element.getAttribute('data-stock');
            fetch(`/panier/${rowId}`,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
                    },
                    method: 'PATCH',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        qty: this.value,
                        stock: stock
                    })
```

the flash message from my controller

```
 if ($data['qty'] > $data['stock']) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Il n\'y a plus assez de stock.');
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Enought Product Quantity']);
        }
```